# Bigtable in BigQuery "Failed to create table: Not found"

Tags: google-bigquery, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Trying to add an external Bigtable table to BigQuery by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable). I've double checked my `PROJECT_ID`, `INSTANCE_ID` and `TABLE_ID` are all correct and have seemingly conducted my URL properly following the prescribed format `https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/instances/[INSTANCE_ID]/tables/[TABLE_NAME]`.

When I attempt to create the table, I get an error message:

```
Failed to create table: Not found: URI https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/...
```

[image: Error]

Searched around to see if anyone else has encountered this, but haven't seen anything. The instance in question is a development instance, I'm not sure if that matters for BigQuery or not. Anyone know if there's additional IAM configuration needed for BigQuery to be able to access the table?

Comment: I think the issue is the zone that the instance was created in. [The docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable) indicate instances have to be located in `us-central1-b` and `us-central1-c` for BigQuery to work but I'm unable to create an instance in those zones. I only have `us-central1-f`.

Comment: I've raised an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72240210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the UI is missing some zones from the drop down. Use the `gcloud` tool instead, and set the desired zone that will work with BigQuery. For example:

`gcloud beta bigtable instances create bigstuff --cluster=bigstuff-cluster --cluster-zone=us-central1-b --cluster-num-nodes=3 --description=stuff`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under advanced settings, ensure it is set to "write if empty" and not append or overwrite if the table is being created for the first time.

Answer (score -1):

I had experience similar Error ,where table is not been created and some unknown error popup in dialog

The way I  solved it just Closed down all of my chrome browser and refresh my pc and then restart the browser .
This time every thing worked fine